# How can I upgrade from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.10?

Tags: 18.10, 19.10, do-release-upgrade

Every time I try to upgrade to 19.10, I get a message saying “An upgrade from ‘cosmic’ to ‘eoan’ is not supported with this tool”. How can I upgrade?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 was only tested in upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04, thus that's the only supported path. A re-install however is still an option (using 'something-else', don't select format and it'll note your packages, erase system dirs, install, add back your additional software & ask to reboot; it won't touch user files unless you format). You're trying to do something that is not officially supported, nor tested for, so be prepared for problems that may occur unless you re-install.

Comment: i followed https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2020/02/21/upgrading-from-an-unsupported-ubuntu/ successfully \o/

Comment: Glad to hear that Holger! That link is my blog post about an upgrade. It boils down to modifying do-release-upgrade a little bit so it upgrades cosmic to disco. It all still works, just the tool isn't able to do it without some hacking.

Comment: This question was inappropriately closed as having answers. Fortunately the exact same question a week later survived: see it with an an swer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208109/how-to-upgrade-from-18-10-to-19-10-using-the-command-line